# Insertar Datos (union de label y textbox)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

En mi interfaz tengo 7 label con datos ya predeterminados y 7 textbox, cada textbox va ligado a un label. Lo que quiero es que cuando se escriba un número en un textbox que esta al frente del label sólo se inserte el valor en el código que indica el label, hasta el momento sólo puedo insertar en un solo campo de la base de datos y el código que estoy manejando es el siguiente:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo_integra", lbCodigo1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", textBox1.Text);
```

Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer con los otros 6 campos que me hacen falta porque si yo coloco el mismo código y le cambio el label y el textbox me sale un error que ya esta usando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi base de datos tengo varios códigos y cada código corresponde a un producto. Lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario digite un número en el texbox, ese número se guarde en la base de datos. Ejemplo si en el código 284 en el textbox dan 5 en la base de datos me guarde esos 5, si en el código 288 en el textbox dan 10 en la base de datos me guarde esos 10 pero solo y únicamanete al producto que está ligado ese código 288 o 284.

Comment: Podrias explicarlo mejor? No logro entender lo que quieres.
El usuario mete un numero en el texbox y que tiene que pasar? Porqué no usas una coleccion y vas metiendo ahi los datos y luego los recorres y asignas valores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando en internet encontre este codigo

```
 private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MiCadenaConexion"))
        {
            con.Open();
            string consulta = "Insert into miTabla (...) values (@codigo_integram @cantidad)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, con);

            //Recorro el form y obtengo los TextBox que no son vacíos, 
            //y los ordeno por el nombre ascendente
            List<TextBox> inputs = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().
                             Where(t => t.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                             .OrderBy(t => t.Name).ToList();

            foreach (TextBox txt in inputs)
            {
                //Obtengo el número identificador
                string num = txt.Name.Substring(txt.Name.Length - 1, 1);

                //Busco el Label que tenga el nombre lbCodigo#
                //dónde # es el número que encontré
                Label lbl = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().
                                  Where(x => x.Name == string.Concat("lbCodigo", num)).
                                  FirstOrDefault();

                //Si no es nulo, es porque encontró
                if (lbl != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo_integra", lbl.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", txt.Text);

                    //Ejecutamos la consulta
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }//fin lbl
            }//fin foreach
        }//fin using
    }
```

y este me funciona correctamente, y les dejo como se ve reflejado en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]